# Laravel Dynamic Image in Bootstrap Container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I have a laravel app that allows me to upload tours and eventually will allow users to do it too. On my single view tour page (which hopefully there will be hundreds) each Tour has it's own cover image amongst others. This is uploaded by me or the user to our DB which I call via src="{{ $tour->coverPhoto }}"

I tried looking for a solution to this, but can't seem to find one. I want to have another div inside this coverPhoto so I can put information above the coverPhoto.

Here is what I have so far: (I'm using bootstrap)

CSS

```
.bg-image {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: scale(1.03);
}
.bg-image img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100vh;
    max-width: 1900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    filter: url(blur.svg#blur);
    -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
    filter: blur(10px);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="bg-image">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/1900x900">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                <p> hi</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                <p>hi</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I made a JSfiddle that mostly shows what's happening. Any help is appreciated thank you!
https://jsfiddle.net/c1tn14ta/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this might help, see the use of position and z-index.

http://codepen.io/simondavies/pen/ONKLpx

HTML

```
  <div class="image-outer-wrapper">
    <div class="image-wrapper"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></div>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <div class="content">
        content here...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
  .image-outer-wrapper {
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
    max-height: 300px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .image-wrapper {
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    z-index: 30;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .content-wrapper {
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 40;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  }

  .content {
    margin:0;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
```

Comment: That totally works for me! Thank you so much. Really helped after 4-5 hours of headache just on this.